# Rails, A method to be called only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, filter, environment-variables

I remember seeing this somewhere online but I know have trouble finding information about it. In Rails 3.1, I have a method at the beginning of a session controller, force_ssl, I only want it called in a production environment, how do I do that?

To clarify, the code looks something like this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    force_ssl
end
```

Comment: This is a *very* bad idea. You don't want to do that. You want the production environment to run identical code to the test environment. Otherwise there is no point in having a test environment.

Comment: @EJP Normally I agree. But there are big problems testing SSL with capybara and Selenium. Turning off SSL in test mode solves the problem for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rails.env.production?` returns true if the current environment is 'production'. More generally, `Rails.env.somestring?` returns true if `Rails.env == "somestring"`. From there you should be good.

** EDIT **

Well actually, there's an easier way to use ssl only in production. Check out [this article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what the syntax should be? I tried: force_ssl if Rails.env.production?   But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. force_ssl caused problems by testing with capybara and selenium. This here solved my problems and the tests are now running:

```
force_ssl if Rails.env.production?
```

I am using the line above in some Controllers. For example in the SessionController and UserController.